# PHPでディレクトリ内のディレクトリの一覧を再帰的に取得したい

Tags: php

お世話になります。
PHPでディレクトリ内のディレクトリ一覧をすべて取得したく、下記のようなコードを作成しました。
しかし、取得した結果が空の配列になってしまいます。
下記のコードで間違っている点等、何かアドバイスをいただけますと幸いです。

### ソースコード

```
function get_all_dir($dir){
  $list = array();
  $dirs = glob(rtrim($dir, "/")."/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR|GLOB_ERR);
  foreach ($dirs as $value){
    if (is_dir($value)){
      $list = array_merge($list, get_all_dir($value));
    }
  }
  return $list;
}

var_dump(get_all_dir("./test"));
```

### 実行結果

```
array(0) { }
```

### 環境

PHP7.4.1

---

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/class.directoryiterator.php) を使って書いてみました。

```
function get_all_dir($dir){
  $dirs = [];
  foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDir() && ! $fileInfo->isDot() &&  ! $fileInfo->isLink()) {
      $d = rtrim($dir, '/').'/'.$fileInfo->getFilename();
      $dirs = array_merge($dirs, [$d], get_all_dir($d));
    }
  }
  return $dirs;
}

var_dump(get_all_dir('./test'));
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。この方法でうまくいきました。

Answer (score 0):

こんにちは。自分ならこうという感じですが、書いてみました。
$listを関数の最初に初期化してるのが原因だと思います。再帰した値を保持するには参照で渡さないといけないですね。クラスならメンバ変数に格納するのもいいでしょう。
また`..`は上位ディレクトリを表すので無視します。

```
<?php
function get_all_dir($dir,&$list){
    if($dir == '..') return;
    $dirs = glob(rtrim($dir, "/")."/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR|GLOB_ERR);

    foreach ($dirs as $value){
        if (is_dir($value)){
          $list[]=$value;
          get_all_dir($value,$list);
      }
    }
    return;
}
$list = [];
get_all_dir(__DIR__,$list);
print_r($list);
```